# Can not copy into char array from argument via strcpy

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void doSth(char *a)
{
    char *b,*c;
    b = malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    b[0]='a';
    b[1]='\0';

    a = malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    c = malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(a,b);
    strcpy(c,b);

    printf("c:%s\n",c);
    free(c);
    free(b);
}


int main()
{
    char *myString;

    doSth(myString);

    printf("%s\n",myString);

    free(myString);
    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs only "c:a".
Why can't I copy b to a? According to the debugger, the variable "a" remains empty in every line.

Comment: Hint: C has pass by value semantics for function arguments.

Comment: always check the returned value from malloc (and family) (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `a = malloc(2*sizeof(char));` in function `void doSth(char *a)`, a local copy of `a` is modified in the scope of the function, but not out of it. If you wish to modify `myString`, a pointer to `myString` (`&myString`) should be given to the function. It is called passing by pointer :

```
char *myString;

doSth(&myString);
```

The prototype of the function is changed accordingly :

```
void doSth(char **a){
  ...
  *a = malloc(2*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(*a,b);
  ...
}
```

For the same reason, it is `int a=1;printf("%d",a);` (`printf` just needs the value of `a`), but `int a;scanf("%d",&a);` (`scanf` needs a pointer to `a`, to modify the value of `a` in the main).